# Add label to ReferenceLine in recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, label, recharts

I want to add a `<Label/>` to a `<ReferenceLine/>`.
This works but I want the `<Label/>`s position to be on the line (or near the line) instead of being in the right corner (-> image).

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ReferenceLine type="monotone" y={props.data.avgAll} fill="violett" stroke="#8884d8">
   <Label content={<AverageCircle/>} position={"center"}/>
</ReferenceLine>
```

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Change the position from `center` to `top`

```
<ReferenceLine type="monotone" y={props.data.avgAll} fill="violett" stroke="#8884d8">
   <Label content={<AverageCircle/>} position={"top"}/>
</ReferenceLine>
```

you can refer to the documentation [here](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Label)